# What is the normal fan speed?

Tags: 16.04, dell, fan, fancontrol

I am using Dell 5471 that is my sensors data, is that a normal (maybe i am obsessive about fan noise) What is your opinion this ?

```
  acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan: 3001 RPM
CPU:            +44.0°C  
Ambient:        +39.0°C  
SODIMM:         +42.0°C  
Other:          +46.0°C
```

Comment: That sounds about right, especially for a thin laptop.

Comment: but always it is 3000+ rpm. It has to be sometimes 0